# How to make items invisible in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, visible

This may sound like a simple question which I'm sure has a simple solution, but basicaly... I'm making an actionscript game, and I want the player to be able to click on a book and then for a key to appear. I can get both these elements to disappear. I just can't figure out how to have the key invisible until someone clicks the book.

Here is the code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

book.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,getBook);
key.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,getKey);
//door.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoBedroom);

var gotBook:Boolean = false;
var gotKey:Boolean = false;


function getKey(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    if(gotBook==false){
        key.visible = false;
    }else{
        key.visible = true;
    }
}

if(gotBook==true){
    book.visible = false;
    key.visible = true;
    }


function getBook(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    book.visible = false;
    key.visible = true;

}
```

Comment: Can you list the exact steps you want to happen in list format, like step1: everything is invisible, etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set its `visible` property to false at the point that it is added to the stage.

Assuming that your code is on the frame where these objects are added, you can set it to invisible as you create your listeners:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

book.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,getBook);
key.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,getKey);
//door.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoBedroom);

var gotBook:Boolean = false;
var gotKey:Boolean = false;

key.visible = false;
```

Comment: thank you! i knew the solution was going to be this simple, i blame exam stress!

Comment: No worries, but please mark this as the correct answer if it has solved your problem.